# HTML5 Placeholder feature detection woes

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder, jslint, browser-feature-detection

I need to test for placeholder support. The following works great in all modern browsers, as well as IE7, IE8, IE9:

```
$.support.placeholder = (function () {
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    return "placeholder" in i;
}());
```

It works, but JSLint complains about the use of `in`:

> Unexpected 'in'. Compare with undefined, or use the hasOwnProperty
>   method instead.

Fine, so I'll refactor it to this:

```
$.support.placeholder = (function () {
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    return i.hasOwnProperty("placeholder");
}());
```

Now this passes JSLint without any errors or warnings, but it breaks in IE7 and IE8 with this old chestnut:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'hasOwnProperty'

Any idea how to make JSLint happy, as well as IE7 and IE8?

Comment: Making a tool like jslint happy doesn't necessarily mean making your code better as long as you know what you are doing. If your bosses want it, give them some good examples proving them stupid.

Comment: I don't no why jslint recommends against `in`. It's been around for a while so should have full support and it's pretty intuitive. For placeholder support, this is solid: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could also use the other solution JSLint suggests:

```
return typeof i.placeholder !== 'undefined';
```

This should work cross browser without problems.

Comment: This also works well, and is pretty concise, and if I had bothered reading into the error message I should have figured this out :)

Comment: Actually JSLint wants you to use `return i.placeholder !== undefined;` and it'll say as such if you try and use `typeof i.placeholder !== 'undefined';`.

Answer (score 5):

My answer would be don't. Don't make JSLint happy. JSLint is how Crockford views JavaScript should be done. It's his personal standard. If you want some kind of lint for JavaScript, use [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/). It's a forked version of JSLint that is entirely configurable and without the crazy requirements. From it's homepage:

> JSHint is a fork of JSLint, the tool written and maintained by Douglas
>   Crockford.
>
> The project originally started as an effort to make a more
>   configurable version of JSLint—the one that doesn't enforce one
>   particular coding style on its users—but then transformed into a
>   separate static analysis tool with its own goals and ideals.

Comment: Agreed, but not my decision unfortunately. I must live with it, at least for the time being. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch the function via `Object.prototype`, then `call` it on the element. This makes for the function being available *and* you being able to call it in a `i.hasOwnProperty`-fashion way (i.e. the `this` value behind the scenes when calling it is `i`):

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i, "placeholder");
```

Comment: Hmm, which one would you go with.

Comment: @karim79: This one allows for the property being set to `undefined`, but on the other hand does introduce a function call overhead.